# Cache not updating in child component

Tags: reactjs, caching, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Im working on a chat app that uses Apollo client and React

I made my Messages Window component run a cache update in the componentDidMount.

My goal is to update the unread count when the messages are opened. This updates when getting the message but the frontend UI needs the optimistic ui update.

I refresh the page:
First click causes no response...
Every click after that seems to update the previous.
Any ideas?

Here's my onload for the component
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Did have setup redux in your app then call action at when user open message and you will get new data at componentwillreceve method via reducer  then you can do what ever you want